# Relação ternaria com uma chave estrangeira não obrigatória

Tags: mysql, banco-de-dados, modelo-relacional

Tenho uma banco de dados com três entidades que se relacionam: usuário, processo_seletivo e cursos. O objetivo é modelar o banco para satisfazer as seguintes exigências:

- O usuário pode se inscrever em vários processos seletivos
- Cada processo seletivo pode, ou não, ter cursos relacionados(dependendo do tipo do processo).
- Quando um processo seletivo possuir cursos o usuário deve selecionar os cursos que deseja participar e também definir uma prioridade pra cada um, pois será selecionado para apenas um.

Tendo em vista que cursos e prioridade não são campos obrigatórios - pois existem processos que não possuem cursos. Será que a melhor forma de fazer seria usando relação ternária com as três chaves estrangeiras?

dessa forma ficaria:

tabela_inscrições

```
id_usuario (FK)(PK)(NN)
id_processo (FK)(PK)(NN)
id_curso (FK)(quando o processo não tiver curso, esse campo será NULL)
prioridade(quando o processo não tiver curso, esse campo será NULL)
```

Se estiver correto, como ficaria a consulta para selecionar todos os processos que um usuário está inscrito juntamente com os cursos e a prioridade entre eles.

Sou iniciante e esse problema me pareceu bastante complexo. Alguém poderia ajudar?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A estrutura da base de dados me parece perfeitamente adequada, eu provavelmente faria da mesma maneira.

A consulta não é tão complicada. Você vai precisar de um `JOIN` para cada uma das tabelas relacionadas. Como é garantido haver um usuário e um processo para cada inscrição, use `INNER JOIN` com essas tabelas. Como curso pode estar em branco, você precisará de um `LEFT JOIN`, ou os resultados só incluirão as inscrições que tiverem curso.

A query fica assim:

```
SELECT
     usuario.id AS id_usuario,
     usuario.nome AS nome_usuario,
     processo.id AS id_processo,
     processo.nome AS id_processo,
     curso.id AS id_curso,
     curso.nome AS nome_curso,
     inscricao.prioridade
FROM inscricoes inscricao
    INNER JOIN usuarios usuario
    ON usuario.id = inscricao.id_usuario
    INNER JOIN processos processo
    ON processo.id = inscricao.id_processo
    LEFT OUTER JOIN cursos curso
    ON curso.id = inscricoes.id_curso
WHERE inscricoes.id_usuario = 1 -- parametrize aqui
ORDER BY processo.nome ASC, curso.prioridade DESC, curso.nome ASC
```

Comment: Obrigado por responder, @bfavaretto. Deu certo a query. Mas tive que incluir uma chave primaria para identificar cada tupla de inscrição, pois não dava para inserir um usuário inscrito no mesmo processo seletivo mas em um curso diferente. Isso ocorria porque os campos id_usuario(PK) e id_processo(PK) iriam se repetir.

Comment: Ok, acho que é por causa das FKs. Sem essas chaves, não haveria o impedimento, creio.